# UTF-8'en-us' prefix to downloads

Tags: firefox, utf-8, download, prefix

We often need to download files (csv, sas7bdat) from a pharmaceutical application we use. However, when using Firefox, all file names get prefixed with **UTF-8'en-us'** which whilst not critical is annoying and time consuming. We do not have this issue with IE or Chrome. Is there a setting we can change to stop this happening.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Different departments have different versions. On my personal PC I have 38.4.0 on the company laptop we have 31.8.0